# hyperref causes a gap between the figure and subcaption with memoir

Tags: spacing, hyperref, memoir, subfloats, subcaption

I'm experiencing a strange problem with `memoir` subfigure captions together with `hyperref`. Below is a working example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tb]
  \rule{\textwidth}{4ex}
  \subcaption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following result:

[image]

If I remove the `hyperref` package and recompile, the gap disappears:
[image]

Anyone have any idea why this is happening, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to place `%` behind the `\rule` line:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tb]
  \rule{\textwidth}{4ex}%
  \subcaption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I guess that `\subcaption` uses `\unskip` to remove the space cause by the line break, but `hyperref` adds some internal code which stops `\unskip` to go that far back. Because the `\rule` is `\textwidth` long the space is creating a new line if not removed. Alternatively add a manual `\unskip` before `\subcaption` if you have a more complicated content than `\rule`.

In general it is a good idea to place a `%` after `}` and `{` at the end of a source line. Such spurious spaces are appearing often if you are not careful.

Comment: In my document where this problem occurs (it's only in one subfigure - in all other subfigures there is no gap), I had to use both `\unskip` and place a `%` after the figure code. Anyhow, the gap is now gone. Thanks.